# Stored Procedure has void type instead of returning my desired result

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

This is my Stored Procedure implementation :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ShowProjectByNameOfPerson]
(@name as nvarchar)
as begin

select   Personality.id,COUNT(*) as cnt into  #test 
 from Personality,Project,Personal_project
where Personality.Id = Personal_project.PersonalityId_FK
and Project.Id = Personal_project.ProjectId_FK
and Personality.FullName like N'%'+@name+'%'
group by Personality.Id
order by cnt desc
select * from #test,Personality
where #test.id = Personality.id
end
```

I create Linq ToSQL Classes Item in my ASP.Net project.and i assigned the procedures to the DBML file.
But when i want to using the procedure after making instance of the context i get this errors :

```
Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

No overload for method 'ShowProjectByNameOfPerson'
```

And this is the calling code for stored procedure in .cs file :

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
var lst = db.ShowProjectByNameOfPerson(txt);
```

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: It's bad practice to use "select *" in your stored proc. If the table is changed your program has no way of knowing about it and will fail. If you specifically call out columns the change will not break your program.

Comment: Are you using nullable typed variables in your program?

Answer (score 3):

You are confused by the various t-sql function types.

What you want is:

```
create function [dbo].[ShowProjectByNameOfPerson] (@name as nvarchar)
returns table
as return (
  select
    Personality.Id, Personality.FullName, 
    COUNT(*) as cnt
  from Personality
  inner join Personal_project 
    on Personality.Id = Personal_project.PersonalityId_FK
  where Personality.FullName like N'%' + @name + N'%'
  group by Personality.Id, Personality.FullName
  order by cnt desc
);
```

See the MSDN reference to understand the syntax variations and their meaning:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

Also, you should try to avoid using temporary tables needlessly (see how I changed your code).